# How to do 3D line plots grouped by two factors with the Plotly package in R?

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, grouping, line-plot

I have checked up the [official webpage of Plotly](https://plotly.com/r/3d-line-plots/), but how to plot the following task still escapes me:

```
id <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5))
t <- rep(seq(50,75,length.out=5), 4)
x <- runif(20) + sin(t) 
y <- rnorm(20) + cos(t)
gender <- c(rep("F",10), rep("M",10))
smoke <- c(rep("Y",5), rep("N",10), rep("Y",5))

DATA <- data.frame(ID, t, x, y, gender, smoke)

fig <- plot_ly(DATA, x = ~t, y = ~y, z = ~x, .......)
```

Suppose I have 4 groups of patients (grouped by 2 factors, Female/Male and Smokers/Non-smokers), each associated with 5 observations $(x_i, y_i)$ along the timestamps $t_i$. So I need to draw a 3D line plot $${(t_i, x_i, y_i)}_{i=1}^{i=5}$ for each patient, but all in one plotting canvas. If I want to represent **genders by red/blue, smokers by solid and non-smokers by dash lines**, and specify these in the legend, what should I do (ideally using R)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of 3D plot you have in mind can be achievd like so:

```
library(plotly)

id <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5))
t <- rep(seq(50,75,length.out=5), 4)
x <- runif(20) + sin(t) 
y <- rnorm(20) + cos(t)
gender <- c(rep("F",10), rep("M",10))
smoke <- c(rep("Y",5), rep("N",10), rep("Y",5))

DATA <- data.frame(id, t, x, y, gender, smoke)

col_gender <- c(M = "red", F = "blue")
lt_smoke <- c(Y = "solid", N = "dash")
sym_id <- c(`1` = "circle", `2` = "square", `3` = "diamond", `4` = "cross")

fig <- plot_ly(DATA, 
               x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~t, symbol = ~id, color = ~gender, linetype = ~smoke, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines+markers',
               line = list(width = 6),
               marker = list(size = 3.5, cmin = -20, cmax = 50),
               colors = col_gender,
               linetypes = lt_smoke,
               symbols = sym_id)
fig
```

### Edit:

In case of more patients the best option is to map `id` on color and additonally group by `id` using transform `groupby`

```
library(plotly)

id <- c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5), rep(5,5), rep(6,5), rep(7,5), rep(8,5))
t <- rep(seq(50,75,length.out=5), 8)
x <- runif(40) + sin(t) 
y <- rnorm(40) + cos(t)
gender <- c(rep("F",10), rep("M",10), rep("F",10), rep("M",10))
smoke <- c(rep("Y",5), rep("N",10), rep("Y",5), rep("Y",5), rep("N",10), rep("Y",5))

lt_smoke <- c(Y = "solid", N = "dash")
sym_id <- c(M = "circle", F = "square")

fig <- plot_ly(DATA, 
               x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~t, symbol = ~gender, color = ~id, linetype = ~smoke, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines+markers',
               line = list(width = 6),
               marker = list(size = 3.5, cmin = -20, cmax = 50),
               linetypes = lt_smoke,
               symbols = sym_id,
               transforms = list(
                 list(
                   type = 'groupby',
                   groups = ~id)
               ))
fig
```

Comment: Thank you! But does it draw a separate 3D line plot for each patient (a.k.a for every 5 observations)? I was expecting `id` involved or `add = TRUE` somewhere.

Comment: Hi. And sorry. I read over the part with the id in your question. (: In general: No different lines for patients. The data is only grouped by combinations of gender and smoke. In this sense the plot has different lines for the 4 ids given in the example data. To explicitely group by id, one approach would be to map id e.g. on symbol which results in different marker types. However, at least for the example data this doesn't make any difference. But if your have more groups of patients it probabyly will.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I know there're a lot asked in my post ^_^

Comment: Actually I have 60 patients, and the reason why I want to add data patient by patient instead of mapping ID to symbols is that (1) 60 symbols are just too many (2) each line plot should reflect how things develop for each patient, so I need to get rid of the line segment between the 5th and the 6th, the 10th and the 11th ... data point. The best thing I can think of is to start over. Do you know how to do that? Or is it impossible with Plotly?

Comment: Yep. Mapping id on symbols is not feasible in that case. IMHO the best and simplest option in this case would be to map id on color and to map gender on symbol instead.

Comment: Yeah then there's still the problem of cutting off line segments between patients.

Comment: Hi. Just added an edit. Had to add more patients to the data to see your point. The trick is to group the data by id which can be achieved via a transform of type groupby.

Comment: Oh that's clever. Thank you! Why are there two `list()` on the right to `transforms` though?